# Uploading PDF's using Dropzone.js & Laravel. Some upload successfully, others return an empty object?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, laravel, file-upload

I'm attempting to use Dropzone.js to upload some files to my PHP environment which runs Laravel 4.2. I've encountered a very confusing bug where **some PDF's will upload successfully, and others will not**.

And when I say some don't upload successfully, I mean this what is available in `Input::all()` upon an upload:

```
[file] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
    (
        [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
        [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => presskit.pdf
        [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => application/octet-stream
        [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
        [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 1
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => 
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => 
    )
```

You'll notice immediately, that some things are wrong:

1. the mimetype is delcared as `application/octect-stream`. This indicates the actual mimetype was unable to be resolved.
2. The file size is `0`.
3. The error is `1`.

Yet, during the request to the server, I can see very clearly that my request is being sent with a mimetype of `application/pdf`:

```
-----------------------------6541909715113
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="presskit.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

That is the start of the data that is sent to the server. On the client side, I can reproduce this in all browsers. Here is my dropzone.js functionality:

```
Dropzone.options.uploadedFilesDropzone = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFilesize: 1024, //MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {

        var uploadedFilesDropzone = this;

        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
            uploadedFilesDropzone.processQueue();
        });
    }
    successmultiple: function(files, message) {
        var uploadedFilesDropzone = this;
        console.log(files);
        var wereAnyFilesErrored = false;
        $.each(files, function(index, file) {
            if (!message.errors) {
                file.previewElement.classList.add('dz-success');
                console.log(message);
            } else {
                wereAnyFilesErrored = true;
                var node, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
                if (file.previewElement) {
                    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
                    if (typeof message !== "String" && message.error) {
                        message = message.error;
                    }
                    _ref = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-errormessage]");
                    _results = [];
                    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                        node = _ref[_i];
                        _results.push(node.textContent = message);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if (wereAnyFilesErrored === true) {
            $.each(files, function(index, file) {
                file.status = 'queued';
                console.log(file);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, there does not appear to be any distinction between whether a PDF uploads correctly or not. Initially, I thought that it may have to do with the PDF version it was saved as, but both 1.4 & 1.6 can be successful or produce failures.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Some php installations have a very tight limit for file uploads. It just may be the size of the document. Can you check your php.ini?

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked something so simple like that. My directive for file uploads was set to 2M -_-. Thank you Kai, you should post your comment as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some php installations have a very tight limit for file uploads. It just may be the size of the document. Can you check your php.ini?

The entry will look like this:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```